# Give a message box where yes no question should be answered

Tags: c#, 2d

Message boxes, had some time put in creating some for my program, now it all were informative message boxes where an OK button was available and then it closed.

I worked with a canvas that would be enabled when needed and gets disabled on clicking OK.

But now I'm in need of a messagebox that gives an output.
I've tried to do the same and test some stuff with public variables, but my code kept going and didn't wait for the response of the "dialogue box" which results in the changes going through and an unused canvas that opened behind my active screen. (Another canvas is loaded when running the code while the current canvas gets disabled).

Code example:

```
 cnvCleanup.enabled = true;
 //Here it should wait till i have "answered" on cnvCleanup
 if (CleanUpDone == true)
 {
 usages = 0;
 }
 else
 {
 usages++;
```

The cnvCleanup will get disabled on the script I wrote for clicking on the OK button.
In case the Not OK button is clicked the bool CleanUpDone should remain false so there the cnv gets disabled.

EDIT: More code.
The CleanUpDoneis `public bool CleanUpDone;` that gets changed in the cnvCleanup.

```
int usages;  
usages = System.Int32.Parse(AssetList[2]);  
if (usages < 10)  
 {  
 usages++;  
 AssetList[2] = usages.ToString();  
 }  
 else  
 {  
 cnvCleanup.enabled = true;  
 //Here it should wait till i have "answered" on the cnvCleanup  
  if (CleanUpDone == true)  
  {  
  usages = 0;  
  AssetList[2] = usages.ToString();  
  }  
  else  
  {  
  usages++;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete portion of your code? I have an idea on how to help you but I need more information on how exactly you decided to implement things.

Comment: @SamR More code available now :)

Comment: Ok so where is this code called? In a function? At Start? In the update?

Comment: In the update under the check if I'm ticking on the right button. So you could say it's an onclick function.

Comment: Go learn C#, OOP, do algorithms and data structures course, read about SOLID and generics, understand best practices in game dev and Unity, normal patterns, game programming patterns, go through some tutorials on games first while learning stuff above, look at tutorial mistakes and learn actually the logic of code and unity workflow before making game by yourself without tutorial help. It's just an advice, otherwise, you will struggle to find the problems, spend much more time, write not maintainable code and search a long time for what am I doing wrong while getting wrong answers.

Comment: Why do I think so? Well first of all - your answer below, it's awful because unity already checks for the things you wrote on its end, you are just double checking and doing some weird stuff no one can understand. Calling GetComponent in Update, well that is a nice loss of performance. Also, architecture with many bool values that change depending on conditions. Using canvas for 1 element, not elements inside a canvas. Every canvas creates new overhead that you can avoid. System.Int32.Parse()? Why are you saving your data as string to then parse it? Why would you allocate more memory?

Comment: Why use .txt for saving the data? You should use Json or XML with code word at least to make it safer - and for the safest type of saving data - BinnaryFormater. You can find a GDC talk about it on youtube about saving data. I don't blame you, I just encourage you to learn some things before making projects on your own from your ideas, try to repeat something first and learn basics. You will save a lot of time. Good Luck ! Hope, you will be a great game developer one day !

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It sounds a bit negative, but I'll keep your advice in my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code like this:
in the update he checks if he is on one of the needed buttons.
so the mousepointer is on the object and the canvas is active.
when one of the buttons is clicked, he does the code, if none of the buttons are clicked, nothing happens.

```
RectTransform rt = btnCleanupOK.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    if (Input.mousePosition.x > btnCleanupOK.transform.position.x - rt.rect.width /2 && Input.mousePosition.x < btnCleanupOK.transform.position.x + rt.rect.width / 2 && Input.mousePosition.y > btnCleanupOK.transform.position.y - rt.rect.height / 2 && Input.mousePosition.y < btnCleanupOK.transform.position.y + rt.rect.height / 2 && cnvCleanup.enabled == true)
    {
        isOverOK = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isOverOK = false;
    }
```

How to check the button is clicked:

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isOverOK)
    {
        clickedOKButton();
    }
```

In the `clickedOkButton();` is the rest of the code that needed to be run when clicking on OK.

I've done the same for clicking on the later button.
I know this isn't optimal, but it works.